# Trouble understanding method renaming with ASM Bytecode in Java

Tags: java, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation, java-bytecode-asm

I am currently trying to understand how the ASM library works. I've decided to try to rename all the methods of a given class, so I wrote a mini `MethodRenamer` visitor:

```
class MethodRenamer extends ClassAdapter {
    public MethodRenamer(ClassVisitor cv) {
        super(cv);
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        MethodVisitor methodVisitor = cv.visitMethod(access, name+"_new", desc, signature, exceptions);         
        return methodVisitor;
    }
}
```

It actually does me the full job, but I can't understand why. I thought that with the given code it would only, for each method `m`, create a `m_new` method, empty of code. But contrary to my expectation, it somehow fills each `m_new` with the original code.

How can this happen? I had the idea that only what I forward to `cv` would be written in the output file. I am not telling `cv` in any place what the code of the original `m` code is..so I guess there must be something else going on here? The only other viable option seems to be that it is using my returned `methodVisitor` in some way.

Answer (score 2):

The MethodVisitor returned from MethodRenamer.visitMethod() is the one used by ClassReader to fill in the method body. If you want an empty method, then you should return null. See [corresponding JavaDoc](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html#visitMethod%28int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

Comment: But I don't get it. Shouldn't my class reader only *read*? I thought that only things forwarded to class writer would write a thing. Or is class reader sending this returned value to class writer on my back?

Comment: I don't understand your question. However, note that ClassWriter is an implementation of ClassVisitor, which is usually placed at the end of chain of visitors. The ClassReader reads bytecode and produces queue of events feeded to a ClassVisitor instance passed to classReader.accept(..) method. You can look at one of the old ASM tutorials. The API changed slightly, but concepts are still the same http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

I've met with this question in my first time , too.

Maybe it's not clear when reading the tutorial for ASM , as there are many conceptions confused you.

I've got some advice for you to learn.

- First , the concept of [callback in programming.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29).

An example : the system offer you a book, you are requested to read it over. It's your job to write a method to read this book . Everyone has his own reading method , maybe you want to read it quick ,ignoring the chapters you don't interest in, maybe you want to read carefully and slow .Whatever ,it's your job to make a method which implements how you read this book . Then , you give this read method to the system . the system get your method and do what you assigned in your method. This is the process of callback .And I think this will help you most.

- Then , get clear about the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Design patterns are anywhere in program . That's how the ASM framework works I think.
- Finally , turn to the ASM tutorials .

PS:

answer to `Shouldn't my class reader only read?`

Though named as "ClassReader" , its job isn't limited by reading the bytecode. It will invoke other methods through other classes just like the MethodVisitor which is responsible for instrument bytecode in methods . And the MethodVisitor there is just a callback .

The ASM framework which can help you change the bytecode , stay away from facing details of bytecode.